# SCRIPT5009: 'FormData' is undefined in IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have this form that has a Some simple fields in it, First Name, Last name, Address, City, Postal and Phone Number. There is a Cancel and Submit button at the bottom that submits the form.
This form submits and works without any issues on FF, Chrome, Safari, IE10 but NOT on IE9, it's giving me this error "SCRIPT5009: 'FormData' is undefined in IE9 ".

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData` is only supported from IE10. Earlier versions do not have that implemented.

When asking questions, please always provide relevant code, do not explain what your code looks like, better paste it in order to be easier to SO users to help you out.

In order to fix this, you should use a condition in your script in order to check if `FormData` is undefined and if yes, use a fallback method.

Comment: I see, so what sort of workaround or fallback for IE9 would need to be done?

Comment: Ou, Perfect, So I'll check if FormData is undefined and if yes, i'll use a fallback method. That link is for a Progress Upload though, how would it work when submitting a form with strings?

Comment: if it just strings perhaps you should serialize the form instead of using FormData.

Comment: I might do that, thank you for your help. Would you know of any issues with jquery serialize in IE9?